# passing file names with spaces to imagemagic convert

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

Say I have the following files:

```
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_1.jpg'   'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_20.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_10.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_21.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_11.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_22.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_12.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_23.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_13.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_24.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_14.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_3.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_15.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_4.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_16.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_5.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_17.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_6.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_18.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_7.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_19.jpg'  'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_8.jpg'
'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_2.jpg'   'CamScanner 11-06-2022 13.04.24_9.jpg'
```

I would like to convert these files to a pdf. The files aren't currently listed in version order, so this is what I tried:

```
convert $(ls -v) output.pdf
```

But this fails due to the spaces in the file names. I would like to pass the file names to `convert` listed in version order, as well as handle the spaces inside the names. I have seen some SO questions where they sort the files in some order before passing it to convert, but none of those contained any spaces in the file names. Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Edit: I have also tried:

```
ls -v | xargs -I% convert % output.pdf
```

But this only converts a single jpg to pdf.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Are you amenable to a solution that renames your files so the dates are YYYY-MM-DD (so an ASCII sort is identical to a format-aware sort)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yup, I am okay with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote each file name. Or, try this.

```
readlines filearray <(ls -v)
convert "${filearray[@]}" output.pdf
```

A much better solution would use machine-readable dates and zero-padded sequence numbers in the file names, which would make them unambiguous to human readers and solve the sort order problem trivially.

```
for file in CamScanner\ ??-??-????\ ??.??.??_*.jpg; do
    tail=${file##*_}
    printf -v idx %04i ${tail%.jpg}
    mv "$file" "CamScanner-${file:17:4}-${file:14:2}-${file:11:2}_${file:22:8}_$idx.jpg"
done
```

Demo, of sorts: https://ideone.com/Svl6uQ

Comment: Even after quoting the files, only a single jpg is converted to output.pdf
`ls -v | sed "s/^/'/;s/$/'/" | xargs -I% convert % output.pdf`.
Any idea what went wrong here?

Comment: `ls -v` makes `10.2.3` sort after `2.3.4`, but I don't see _how_ that could possibly make MM-DD-YYYY be correct.

Comment: `xargs -I` by definition processes one file at a time.